# Find anchor and add class to closest class

Tags: jquery

Some DIVs will have anchor name called `outage`, and those should addClass `outage` to the parent class `.modAcTitle` and the result would be `<div class="modAcTitle outage">This is a title.</div>` I can't add anything unique to the title, so this was my only concept I could do.

However, my approach below is terrible, because it's adding `.outage` to every  `.modAcTitle` *instead* of titles that contain `outage` anchor in its content.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('a[name=outage]').parent().parent().parent().find('.modAcTitle').addClass("outage")
```

Here is my DIV structure and demo: https://jsfiddle.net/61za2n72/7/

```
<div id="ac_expand_0" class="modAc">
<div class="modAcTitle">This is a title.</div>
<div class="modAcContent" style="display: none;"><p><a name="outage"></a>This is Content and it has a unique name tag called outage</p>
</div>
<div class="modAcTitle">This is a title</div>
<div class="modAcContent" style="display: none;"><p><a name="outage"></a>This is Content and it has a unique name tag called outage</p>
</div>
<div class="modAcTitle">This is a title</div>
<div class="modAcContent" style="display: none;"><p>This is content, but it doesn't have a name tag.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DOM traversal isn't quite correct. You can fix and simplify it by using `closest()` and `prev()`, like this:

```
$('a[name=outage]').closest('.modAcContent').prev('.modAcTitle').addClass('outage');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/61za2n72/8/)

Comment: Can I get your additional help? is there a way to do both at the same time one to addClass "outage" which you've shown me and when the a[name=outage] is NOT present then addClass "none" to the remaining modAcTitle. Oh nevermind. Its $('.modAcTitle:not(".outage")').addClass('none');